# TradingView Pine alertcondition based on color change

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading, trading

I am trying to add `alertcondition` on this pinescript, just to alert me if color of ATR script has changed from green to red and from red to green.

```js
//Crée par J.Dow
    //Double SuperTrend ATR, Le type ATR calcule la volatilité à partir de l'Average True Range (ATR), il est idéal pour le FOREX

    study(title = "Double SuperTrend ATR", shorttitle = "Double SuperTrend ATR", overlay = true)

    //Mode
    Factor=input(title="Super Trend", defval=3, minval=1,maxval = 100)
    ATR=input(title="ATR", defval=12, minval=1,maxval = 100)


    //Super Trend ATR 1
    Up=hl2-(Factor*atr(ATR))
    Dn=hl2+(Factor*atr(ATR))

    TUp=close[1]>TUp[1]? max(Up,TUp[1]) : Up
    TDown=close[1]<TDown[1]? min(Dn,TDown[1]) : Dn

    Trend = close > TDown[1] ? 1: close< TUp[1]? -1: nz(Trend[1],1)

    Tsl1 = Trend==1? TUp: TDown
    Tsl2 = Trend==1? TDown: TUp

    linecolor = Trend == 1 ? green : red



    //Affichage
    P1 = plot(Tsl1, color = linecolor , style = line , linewidth = 1,title = "SuperTrend ATR-1")
    P2 = plot(Tsl2, color = linecolor , style = line , linewidth = 1,title = "SuperTrend ATR-2")
    fill(P1, P2, color = linecolor == red ? red : green)

greenColor = (Trend == 1)
alertcondition(condition=greenColor, title="Buy", message="green buy")
redColor = (Trend != 1)
alertcondition(condition=redColor, title="Sell", message="red sell")
```

I fugured out how to make alert for each color, but how can I put it in one single alert that notificate about changing colors, with message "color changed", for example.

Comment: You should use a variable that is only `TRUE` when the color changes and `FALSE` otherwise. Then use that variable as your alert condition.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Can you please give a hint how to formulate that variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding is you want to detect only the change of colours, which is in fact the variable Trend changing from 1 to not(1) or vice-versa. I recommend:

```
change_detection_flag = Trend != Trend[1]
alertcondition(change_detection_flag,title="Change",message="color changed")
```

Note that this is not looking whether it was green before and now red, nor if it was red before and now green - as requested.

Answer (score 0):

When **Trend** is different from previous **Trend**, you can set the alert
Change this at the end of the code

```
greenColor = Trend == 1 and Trend[1] != 1
alertcondition(greenColor, title="Buy", message="green buy")
redColor = Trend != 1 and Trend[1] == 1
alertcondition(redColor, title="Sell", message="red sell")
```